# How to fill all space in parent Relative layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I created a small example to explain my problem. In the example I created a RelativeLayout that fills the whole screen. And 3 children :

1. FrameLayout with id middle that must fill all empty space without overlay on top and bottom of FrameLayout (pink)
2. FrameLayout with id top that must show above middle (red)
3. FrameLayout with id bottom that must show below middle (yellow)

**layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/middle"
        android:background="#FFFF0000" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFF00FF" />   

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/middle"
        android:background="#FFFFFF00" />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot of my example result:**

[image]

**And the screenshot what I need to do:**

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this code should do it.

**Check it out :**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="#FFFF0000"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF00"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/middle"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
    android:layout_below="@id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFF00FF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="#FFFF0000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFF00FF" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF00"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFF00FF" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="#FFFF0000" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FFFFFF00" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `RelativeLayout` you can use `LinearLayout` and make use of `layout_weight` to fill the remaining space.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="#FFFF0000" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/middle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFF00FF"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with relative layout you need to align top and bottom layouts to borders, and than set the middle layout in relation between them.

See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="pl.orbitemobile.myapplication.MainActivity">
    
    
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/top"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="#FFFF0000" />
    
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/middle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/top"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
                android:background="#FFFF00FF" />
    
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/bottom"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#FFFFFF00" />
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Effect:

[image]