# How to fill remaining space in layout without overdraw another elements?

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a new small example to explain my new problem. In the example I created a RelativeLayout that fills the whole screen. And 3 children :

1. Custom view (PView) created to draw proportional view that must fill all free space by width in portrait mode and free space by height in landscape mode without overlay on top and bottom of FrameLayout (pink)
2. FrameLayout with id top that must show above middle (red)
3. FrameLayout with id bottom that must show below middle (yellow)

But now in landscape mode middle item overdraw top and bottom. Have anyone idieas how to fix it ?

**layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFF0000" />


    <test.com.heighttest.PView
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#FFFF00FF" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PView.java**

```
package test.com.heighttest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


/**
 * Created by Anton Potekhin (Anton.Potekhin@gmail.com) on 26.09.16.
 */
public class PView extends RelativeLayout {

    public static final int USE_FOR_SCALE_WIDTH = 0;
    public static final int USE_FOR_SCALE_HEIGHT = 1;

    public int getUseForScale() {
        return useForScale;
    }

    public void setUseForScale(int useForScale) {
        this.useForScale = useForScale;
    }

    private int useForScale = 0;

    public float getAspectRatio() {
        return aspectRatio;
    }

    public void setAspectRatio(float aspectRatio) {
        this.aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
    }

    /**
     * Aspect ratio to calculate size of view. Set 0 to not use aspect ratio (Works like RelativeLayout).
     */
    private float aspectRatio = 0;

    public PView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //Use aspect ratio only if it more than 0
        if (aspectRatio > 0) {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            if (useForScale == USE_FOR_SCALE_WIDTH) {
                height = Math.round(width / aspectRatio);
            } else {
                width = Math.round(height * aspectRatio);
            }
            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package test.com.heighttest;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PView middleView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        com.facebook.stetho.Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        middleView = (PView) findViewById(R.id.middle);
        middleView.setAspectRatio(1.2f);
        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            middleView.setUseForScale(PView.USE_FOR_SCALE_HEIGHT);
        } else {
            middleView.setUseForScale(PView.USE_FOR_SCALE_WIDTH);
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot in portrait mode (Works correctly):**

[image]

**Screenshot in landscape mode (Works incorrect because middle overdraw top and bottom):**

[image]

**Screenshot what i want to get in landscape mode**

[image]

---

Solution by @nidhi-pandya (with my fixes):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="#FFFF0000" />


        <test.com.heighttest.PView
            android:id="@+id/middle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFF00FF" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF00" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill all space in parent Relative layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935591/how-to-fill-all-space-in-parent-relative-layout)

Comment: It's not duplicate. Because it has different behavior of middle item

Comment: Do not create questions that are semantically equal. The duplicate has been pointed, because both are equal questions from you. Please, understand the Layout systems, but dont ask a question for each small change you want. As far as I can tell, you just want a position relative to another view, plus that view half size. Check the `addRule` function to position relative views

Comment: @Bonatti, if you check my question you will see that it different questions. If I use synthetic example visually similar to the old it does not mean that the issues are the same. Anyway i got answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add LinearLayout below Relativelayout and use its orientation to arrange your content vertically. Use alignparenttop, alignparentbottom and centerinparent attribute. It will give you the same output in both orientation.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/top"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#FFFF0000" />


            <test.com.heighttest.PView
            android:id="@+id/middle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#FFFF00FF" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF00" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hm i change in you layout sizes to that i see that it works not fully correctly. Also alignparenttop, alignparentbottom and centerinparent attribute are not work inside linearlayout. But anyway thanks you give me right way to solve my problem. I posted on the top right solution

Comment: Glad to help you..@Anton111111